# Running dotnet ef database update on tfs build agent

Tags: tfs, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make a CD setup which migrates my target database on release in TFS 2017 (update 3). My artifacts only contains my website assemblies, with DB context and controllers etc. If I update my database during build (and not during release) I can run

`dotnet restore
dotnet ef database update`

and it works nicely, but this ofcourse does not work during release, as the source code is not available in the artifacts, and dotnet restore requires the .csproj file.

Anyone have suggestion of how to set up migrations during release? Do I need to include my source in the artifacts?

I'm using .net core 2.0 and ef core 2.0

Comment: I solved this by creating another artifact during my build containing source and binaries of my DBContext library, and then running dotnet commands from the folder with the extracted artifacts during release/deploy. If anyone has a more elegant approach please let me know. I don't think the source code has any business being included in the artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `dotnet ef database update` with the `--verbose` option, you'll see a call to `dotnet exec ef.dll`. This is the command you can use directly on the binaries without needing the source code.

Comment: Thanks, that might prove useful.